# SSH Jupyter notebook using non-base Conda envirnoment?

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, conda

My problem is the following: I want to run a Jupyter notebook on my remote desktop and access  it via my laptop elsewhere. I have accomplished this, but I can't use my GPU for tensorflow because the GPU-supported version is only installed in my custom, non-base environment. Even though all of my installed jupyter kernels are available, it seems things don't work right unless I run 'jupyter notebook' from within the correct activated conda environment (says "no GPU" even though I select as the kernel the one where tensorflow-gpu is installed).

Is there a simple way of running jupyter notebook from within that environment by a batch script? I also need it to run the notebook on a secondary drive.

I could of course just start up the server while at home and then access it using the token, but that's a little clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. On windows, in %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3, there are shortcuts for various Anaconda-related programs, including Jupyter notebook for each environment.

The shortcut for Jupyter notebook for my given env is

`E:\Software\Anaconda3\python.exe E:\Software\Anaconda3\cwp.py E:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\tf E:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\tf\python.exe E:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\tf\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%".

I modified this to end in '"E:" --no-browser' instead of the userprofile bit and made that into a script. Now when I SSH into the computer and run this script, the notebook is within the correct environment and I have access to my GPU, all on the correct drive, E.